# How can I fix output from ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, arraylist

I'm writing a program that reads from a file. Each line in the file contains information about a student.Each student is represented by an object from the class "Student". The class `Student` has a method `getName` that returns the student's name.The method that goes through the file returns and ArrayList containing student objects. My problem is that every time I use a for loop to access the ArrayList and get the name of each student, what I get is the name of the last student in the list. The method that go through the file is called "FileAnalyzer" Below is my code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentStats {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Student> example = null;
    example = FileAnalyzer("C:\\Users\\achraf\\Desktop\\ach.csv");

    for ( int i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(example.get(i).getName());
    }

}

public static List<Student> FileAnalyzer(String path) //path is the path to the file
{ 
    BufferedReader br = null;
    List<Student> info = new ArrayList<Student>();
    String line = "";

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader(path));

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //We create an object "Student" and add it to the list

            info.add(new Student(line));

        }

        }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Aucun fichier trouvé");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finally {
        if (br != null) {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    return info;
}
```

In case you need it, here's the code for the class student

```
// This class create objects for each student

public class Student {

    private static String Name ="";
    private static String Sex = "";
    private static String Grade = "";

    //constructor
    public Student(String infos)
    {
        String [] etudiant = infos.split(",");

        Name = etudiant[0];
        Sex = etudiant[1];
        Grade = etudiant[2];            
    }

    // Getter functions

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }
    public String getSex()
    {
        return Sex;
    }
    public String getGrade()
    {
        return Grade;
    }

}
```

Below is the content of a typical file that the programs reads.

```
lovett,M,12
Achos,F,23
Loba,M,24
```

THE REAL problem is that after running my code to get the names, I get the name "Loba" three times instead of getting all the names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the problem in your `Student` class:

```
private static String Name ="";
private static String Sex = "";
private static String Grade = "";
```

You need to remove the `static` from the member variables otherwise all the objects will share the same attributes and hence you see only the last values written in those variables always.

Learn more about instance and class variables here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Thank you so much ! You deserve a medal ! I should be more careful next time !

Answer (score 2):

Your member variables are declared static in the Student class. That means that they exist as one copy throughout your program, not as one copy per instance which is what you want. Every time you're creating a new student, you're setting the name, sex and grade to something new, but these values are not associated with any particular student. All students share these attributes, and they are being overwritten in your file reading loop, so whatever is the last name in your file will be the name of the static variables.

Comment: Thank you so much ! You deserve a medal ! I should be more careful next time !